# Create object from form params and attribute Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Anyone know how I can write the following as one line?

```
   email = params[:user][:email]
   @user = User.new(:email => email, :password => generate_random_string)
```

I would like  to write it as

```
@user = User.new(params[:user]. :password => generate_random_string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here ya go...

```
@user = User.new(params[:user].merge :password => generate_random_string)
```

Be very careful, allowing the password attribute of a user to be set using mass assignment can have consequences.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its a temporary fix until I implement DEVISE.

Comment: Specifically, `new` takes a Hash of parameters, and `Hash#merge` returns a new Hash with the passed-parameters merged in.